# add a number automatically while calling

Tags: java, android

I have searching for days to resolved my issue..

I want my apk to call a number when i click on a button and while calling (after few seconds)I want my app to add automatically another number(like if we open keyboard of the default dialer view and type a number manually)..

Exemple : when I have a call card to call another country, We have to put some specific number to continue ( put 1 to call to France, put 2 to call to Italia...etc )I want to put AUTOMATICALLY number few seconds after the first ring !

There is my code for now :

```
    public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.num5: // When I click on this button

         Intent localIntent5 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
         localIntent5.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0153204255"));
         startActivity(localIntent5);
         try {
             Thread.sleep(5000);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         Intent localIntent6= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
         localIntent6.setData(Uri.parse("tel:71-0609472130%23"));
         startActivity(localIntent6);

        break;

    }
}
```

Thanks for help..

please help me I'm looking for a days !

Comment: Have you tried adding a comma to the phone number you're dialling?  That might add a pause.

Comment: sorry I begin.. so what is a "comma" ?

Comment: So I have to put "," before "71 0651755275%23" ?? 
But by default how many time it will be paused ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work, but you could try dialling the number in one go, inserting the pause (or pauses) between the two numbers.  More info here: http://www.androidpolice.com/2010/05/10/how-to-add-hard-wait-and-soft-2-3-sec-pauses-to-your-android-contacts/

Comment: it doesn't work Unfortunately
Anyone to resolved my issue.. ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code on button Click:-
num5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent localIntent5 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                localIntent5.setData(Uri.parse("tel:*****"));
                startActivity(localIntent5);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(15000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Intent localIntent6= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                localIntent6.setData(Uri.parse("tel:*******"));
                startActivity(localIntent6);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for reply but it just call the first number (localIntent5) and never call the second number(localIntent6). I want in the same Intent the call and after in the same view dialer add automatically some numbers..( like if when we calling someone open the keyboard and put some number ) and don't really know if i'm clear when I speak sorry for my english..